# change xcrun developer path for Android Studio/IntelliJ

Tags: git, android-studio, intellij-idea, osx-elcapitan, xcrun

I'm using **GIT** and am trying to push my code and getting the following error when using the ***Terminal***. I don't use **XCode**, I'm using ***Android Studio***.

The command I tried using was:

> git branch Networking

Error:

> xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun`

I am running on **El Capitan Beta 4** update if that helps in any way.

---

> **Update**: This also happens for **IntelliJ** users, and for **MacOS
>   Catalina** update

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Instead of installing xcode you can install git from [here](http://git-scm.com/download/mac) and change the path in android studio to `/usr/local/git/bin/git` as shown in the image below.

[image: studio preferences]

This way you save time and memory.

Comment: Saved my time indeed! Thanks @Atrix1987

Comment: This should be marked answer. He asked for android studio and he marked for Xcode answer. I dont know what was wrong with him? By the way thanks for solution.

Comment: After the update to macOS Mojave, this was exactly the suggestion in Android Studio, to install git from this link. But your answer helped with quickly setting the correct path.

Comment: update 2020: just happened to me after Catalina update, 2018 MBP. Installed git with homebrew, the path was: `/usr/local/bin/git`

Comment: thanks Man ,i waste so much time to download and install Xcode  with no solutions .

Answer (score 110):

I ran into the same problem, however with `svn`.  I found that by installing El Capitan, Xcode was "uninstalled".  I reinstalled Xcode from the App Store and then reinstalled Xcode Command Line Tools via Terminal with

```
xcode-select --install
```

After installation, my `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin` directory reappeared and `svn` started working again.

Comment: Thanks for this, but i am not using XCode, i am using Android Studio

Comment: I should have noted that I am not using Xcode for development, either.  I am using IntelliJ.  A version of `git` and `xcrun` is distributed as part of Xcode Command Line Tools (which is where it appears your `git` is currently configured to be executed from).  If you installed `git` on your own (e.g., `/usr/local/bin`), perhaps your `alias` needs to be reconfigured for `git` to point to your installation instead of the default.

Comment: Running `xcode-select --install` to install Xcode Command Line Tools fixed `git` for me. No need to install the whole Xcode.

Comment: The answer is also useful for final version of El Capitan. It makes git working.

Comment: This seems to happen every few Apple OS releases.  I wonder if they're aware of it.

Answer (score 5):

Use **/usr/local/git/bin/git** as a path

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Git did not work after upgrading Mac OS X High Sierra.

Fortunately, the answer provided by @Rob still works for High Sierra, so there was no need for me to actually change the xcrun developer path and no need to install all of XCode

Answer (score 1):

I lost Git after upgrading to macOS Mojave.

The solution of re-installing XCode CLI still works fine.

In Terminal, type:

```
xcode-select --install
```

... and click "Install" on the prompt.