# IntelliJ - cannot commit file

Tags: intellij-idea, svn, tortoisesvn

In IntelliJ, I cannot commit file (right click -> Subversion -> Commit File), the option is grayed out; however - it is possible to Update File.
[image: IntelliJ-commit]

As a workaround, I am able to commit the file through TortoiseSVN:
[image: SVN Commit]
Could you help me to find out why is this happening?

I tried to configure project Settings -> Version Control:
[image: Version control settings]

And also, according to: [Intellij Annotate Option Grayed Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206015/intellij-annotate-option-grayed-out)
I tried to uncheck 'Use non-modal commit interface' but it didn't work.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have git AND svn repository in the same folder? 
You can hover your mouse over "Commit" button and see the message in the bottom left corner of IDE window - there should be  an explanation why commit is greyed out

Comment: That's right, Git and SVN are in one place, but not exactly in the same folder. SVN is in one of the subfolders of the project. Unfortunately, I don't know why it's done this way.
When I hovered over the greyed out 'Commit File', only 'Commit File' appeared in the lower left corner, but thank you very much for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best, but I found a solution to this problem, if I find anything else, I will definitely update.

1. From 'Version control -> Directory Mappings' I had to remove the Git repository, and leave only Subversion, then 'Commit File' works, but I can't in turn do anything (e.g. change branch) on the Git project (which is logical).
2. Then I cleared VCS log caches and indexes.
3. After that I re-added the Git project to 'Dependency Mappings'.
   The problem is, I can't clear VCS log caches and indexes now, because 'Commit File' will stop working again (so again I'd have to remove Git, clear VCS, and add Git after that).

I'm guessing IntelliJ doesn't know which repository this 'Commit File' is for, so this option is greyed out. However, all options are now available.